# Server inception with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, windows, pdo, server

Im really struggling with this one. I have a new server which runs magical unicorn type applications and on old one which is running a access database (could call it a system)

Ive set it up so i can access phpMyAdmin on the new server via oldbadserver:82 - so in theory i would have expected i could run a php script from anywhere (like i could on the old server) by just using the ip address with the port like this :

```
<?php

    $host="oldserveriphere"; //so because its port 82 its forwarded to the new server
    $username="uname";
    $password="mypassword";
    $dbname="mydbname";
    $port="3306"; //mysql port


    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "I am connected.<br/>";

        // ... continue with your code

        // PDO closes connection at end of script
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'PDO Exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
?>
```

But i get :

> PDO Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'oldserveriphere' (110)

Im i missing something obvious? i feel like its trying to find mysql on the old server because im not acctually putting port 82 in there anywhere, but if i do change it to  `$host="oldserveriphere:82";` then i get :

> PDO Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'oldserveriphere' (2)

Comment: Did you try just instead of ` $port="3306";` do ` $port="82";` ?

Comment: yeah i get PDO Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'oldserveriphere' (2) :(

Comment: port 82 is the iis of the new server and the sql server sits on 3306 so essentially it would be oldserver:82:3306 in a unicorn filled world

Comment: Sounds like you have a networking/firewall/ and/or MySQL server setup issue. PHP will make the call to the DB server no problem but it sounds like the request never makes it there so you need to look at everything along the path to the DB server.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes, yes it does.

Comment: @G.Smith Not sure what to tell you besides get a network admin or sysadmin to help you out.

Comment: @G.Smith Check that your mysql user account has permission to connect from remote hosts.

Comment: it works when the same php file is ran from the server locally so its almost certainly permissions when connecting to mysql externally - but i oly have a my-default.conf and it has nothing to do with ips or anything relevent in it @Gadget

Comment: Try modifying the user from uname@localhost to uname@% if you can. If that connects successfully from the remote machine than consider locking the user down to a specific IP instead of %.

Comment: Ive fixed it by finding a new ini file online, it was sql settings